# Replacing a shared member variable in a Spring binded class

Tags: java

A yet-to-be production released java application code has the below structure(this is there in numerous places). The class loads only once during application context load. This worked fine previously. However when moving to regression environment with multiple threads this will cause concurrency issues due to the shared member variable.

```
Class A {

    private Set<String> codeSet = null;

    public void method() {

        codeSet = SomeRepo.someMethod(session.getUser()); // Heavy repo call, returns user specific data.

        method1();

        method2();

        ....

        methodn();
   }

   private methodn() {
        codeSet.iterator().next(); 
   }
}
```

This issue can be mitigated by changing the variable scope to the method, and having it passed across all subsequent private methods which use this variable. However this involves a lot of changes in the application code.

Is there any clean solution which can resolve the below without much changes. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you mentioned thread issues. e.g race condition or what ?

Comment: the variable can be accessed by concurrent threads resulting in data to be corrupt

Comment: have you tried java ReentrantLock to lock that member until that particular thread has finished with it or synchronization ?

Comment: synchronization will be an overhead here.. and is not considered an option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the issue can be easily solved by applying the following refactoring:

```
// singleton used by multiple threads
class A {

    public void method() {
        Set<String> codeSet = SomeRepo.someMethod(session.getUser()); // Heavy repo call.
        new AProcessor(codeSet).method();
   }
}

// not a singleton, only one thread uses an instance of this class
class AProcessor {
    private final Set<String> codeSet;

    AProcessor(Set<String> codeSet) {
        this.codeSet = codeSet;
    }

    public void method() {
        method1();
        method2();

        ....

        methodn();
   }

   private methodn() {
        codeSet.iterator().next(); 
   }
}
```

Comment: +1 thanks.. seems to be an elegant solution, but still involves a bit of refactoring. Will wait for other solutions, if any, before accepting.